# appConcurrentRequest limit exceed on IIS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, asp.net-core, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I deployed .Netcore MVC on AWS windows server 2019(32gb RAM and 8 cores). 100k concurrent requests because its an online exam application. 100k concurrent request should be entertained. Which server should I use?

Comment: More than one server?

Comment: How much it will cost if i go with more then one server? As I am not sure the problem will  occur.

Comment: Can Azure will be capable for 100k concurrent request? Please advise.

Comment: If you are running a service with 100k concurrent users you need to do some analysis on how much resources that is using. Look at the list of Amazon servers for prices. You can call Amazon or another hosting provider and ask them based on the specifics. They are taking your money so they should tell you.

Answer (score 4):

The concurrent connection configuration depend on the maximum concurrent connection in site's advanced setting, queue length and maximum worker process in application pool advanced setting, maximum thread in thread pool.Besides, I notice the serverruntime/httpruntime has a limit of appconcurrentRequestLimit with 5000. So if you need to achieve the high concurrent request, you could go to
IIS manager->site->configuration editor->system.webServer/serverRuntime->appConcurrentRequest.